# Xamarin Ios Application Freezes when run on debugging

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, ios-simulator

I have Xamarin IOS application its working fine in devices and simulator also but its freeze when I am working on debugging.

Comment: I'm also facing same issue.. Do you find any solution on this?

Comment: Remove all debugging point and try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found actually cause of the issue is that put many debugging points in the application. I resolved that issue by removing extra debugging points.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to occur more often if you have disabled breakpoints. Deleting all break points solved this in my case with VS2017 15.8 and Xamarin.Forms on ios only. I was also debugging over WiFi (although I don't think that mattered)